# How to implement NextRcord and PreviousRecord button using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, visual-studio

I have this simple WPF window below, the textbox is bound to a **StudentName** column in a table called **Students**, in XAML. I'm using EntityFramework 5 for data access.

Now you see this window when you run it, how do I got about implementing the **Next** and **Previous** buttons? I have looked online and paging has been suggested, but isn't there a simple one-line way, similar to the oldschool way of moving the recordset to new row? I don't want to use a datagrid, I need to have a bunch of text boxes later-on on the screen with the ability to press next and previous for browsing.

Even if there isn't a one-line way ( and I don't think there is ) just how do I implement the Next and Previous functionality ?

Thank you :)

[image]

This is my codebehind

```
        public LinqNext()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SchoolEntities schoolEntities = new SchoolEntities();
            MyGrid.DataContext = schoolEntities.Students.ToList();
        }

        private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //What do put here to move to next record
            //(Note this code is obviously "MVVM-FREE"
            //Right now i'd just like to move to next record
        }
```

This is My XAML ( simplified)

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <Button x:Name="NextButton" Content="Next" />
        <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Content="Previous"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="StudentName" Text="{Binding Path=StudentName}" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Look at Skip method. But you have a list, so a better solution would be to keep a reference to current item in list, and increment, decrement this number as necessary.

Comment: What kind of a list does `schoolEntities.Students.ToList();` return?

Comment: @JMk its a list of string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to keep current student Id, then:

```
  var next = schoolEntities.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id > currentId);
  this.StudentName.Text = next.StudentName;
```

Comment: +1 but want to notice that this assumes students should be ordered by id

Comment: thx, this makes sense but that breaks my databinding doesnt it? I'd be manually doing   this.StudentName.Text = next.StudentName; ??

Comment: and..ehm...how do I go about tracking the current id? the text box just gets bound automatically upon startup.I'm not iterating over a list to populate it :(

Comment: To be fair this does answer the question you asked, I think you would be best creating a new question for the things you have mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, actually all I have to do is add a new textbox bound to the ID field and that fixes my problem of getting the current ID.thx. Accepted!